# Splitting the list class into dependent and independent methods

Tags: java

So I am working on this project (for a class) and I have a big "List" class that handles an array of objects and all the dependent methods like getters setters and similar. However I also have stuff like sorting and searching in the same class and I would like to split this class into 2 classes. One that handles all the dependent methods (like getters and setters) and another one that has all the sorting searching and printing. I just tried to copy those methods into a different class, which would be a subclass of the List class, but of course I got a lot of errors by calling stuff that is not in the subclass. Is there a way to split this class automatically so it handles all these errors and changes the sintax the way it would be in order to work? (Unfortunately) I am using Eclipse.

PS: Because I have to submit my project trough safe assign I am not able to share the code, as it would flag a match and I would get a 0 on the project.

Thanks!

Comment: Which ide are you using, intellij have pretty nice support for refactoring.

Comment: There is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_Down in the [refactoring menu](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse/article.html#refactoring_eclipse) which may be something you could use (it moves methods into subclasses, those need to exist though). May not be able to fix all your errors though

Comment: Just a note on design ... If you have one class with just getter and setter and another with logic, you are most probably breaking encapsulation. One class with data and one class with logic is not the way to go. Can you think of a way to just remove the getters and setters ? And expose higher level operations ?

That being said, I have no idea of what you are actually doing, so it might well make sense in your case.

Comment: There are 2 reasons why I need to do this.
1. I have way to many methods and I would like sorts and stuff to be in a separate, calucaltions, class
2. From what I understand this is how our professor wants us to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It does sound like a good idea to split the class but I don't believe extending your list class is good design. Better would be to expose the specific methods used to sort and search (e.g. compare items, find items, iterate through items). Then separate classes could offer various utility methods using the exposed primative methods of your list. This is the approach taken by Java's collection library and is probably the correct one for you as well. It separates the logic for manipulating the list from the various things you want to do with it which is much better encapsulation than using subclassing to expose the internals.

Comment: "I don't believe extending your list class is good design". Neither do I. `java.util` is a good example how to get it right. The sorting and searching stuff is mostly not in the collection class itself, but in a utility class like `java.util.Arrays` or `java.util.Collections`, and to me that design looks good. If I come up with my own collection, users can still use the methods in `java.util.Collections` for it. (Also explains my +1)